# How to get adsense page views using Google Analytics API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api, adsense

I am trying to get total adsense ads views for a date range using Google Analytics API V3 and google apps script.In my google analytics account adsense views show but I have not find a way to get adsense page view.If it is possible then please give me reference .

PS-I know how to fetch adsense views using adsense management API but I want to fetch this using Google Analytics API to get exact number of page views and clicks.Adsense doesn't included invalid clicks and impressions.

Comment: Have you tried it with http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/
It is a query explorer which underneath is using google analytic api.
We use to first test it with it then implement the query with our preffered language [As i have done it in my .net C# WCF solution]

Comment: Thanks for this awesome tool but I have not find metrics for adsense data.There is metrics for adword but no adsense.

Comment: Have you check it in the dimension area?

Comment: Yes! there is no option for Adsense.I think it's not possible.

Comment: I think in AdWords metric there are number of option which might give you insight into your adsense data
ga:impressions
ga:adClicks
ga:adCost
ga:CPM
ga:CPC
ga:CTR
ga:costPerTransaction
ga:costPerGoalConversion
ga:costPerConversion
ga:RPC
ga:ROI
ga:margin

You can also check https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/adwords

Comment: I have tried every option of Adword but it always shows 0 because I have never used Adword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has now exposed AdSense statistics to the Analytics API. The new metrics are named `ga:adsenseCTR`, `ga:adsenseRevenue`, `ga:adsenseECPM`, `ga:adsenseAdUnitsViewed`, `ga:adsenseAdsViewed`, `ga:adsenseAdsClicks`, `ga:adsensePageImpressions` and `ga:adsenseExits`. I have verified that they actually work.

Read the full story [here](http://analytics.blogspot.de/2013/10/new-adsense-data-in-google-analytics.html)!

Answer (score 2):

Although you can view AdSense data in Google Analytics, the API doesn't currently expose it. AdSense does, however, have its own API that you can access either via [app scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/adsense_scheduled_reports_tutorial) or [REST](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/getting_started).

Comment: This is now finally possible, see my answer.